# Не работает css из за комментария

Tags: css, веб-программирование, комментарии

Есть код, который не работает, если перед ним добавлен комментарий. Стоит его убрать, и все в порядке.

```
<!--============================ Главная секция ============================-->

section#main {
  padding-top: 20px;
  height: 1330px;
  background: url(../bootstrap/img/main-bg.jpg) no-repeat 
  center center;
}
```

Answer (score 7):

На сколько помню у `css` есть только `/* комментарий */`, а `<!--комментарий -->` - это у `html`.

Answer (score 5):

```css
/* ============================ Главная секция ============================ */

section#main {
   padding-top: 20px;
   height: 1330px;
   background: url(../bootstrap/img/main-bg.jpg) no-repeat center center;
}
```

Так работает.